# SharePoint 2013 list form with security

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-form

I am creating a form in SharePoint 2013, I am using standard list form and trying to achieve following.

1. I want a form which people can submit, which then closes and
   provides them with an automated message.
2. I do not want people to be able to see the list of entries as this information is confidential and I want to allow access to certain people to view and update.

questions:

- How can I show a message when form is successfully submitted?
- I have implemented item level security in list settings, so user can see only their created forms only but how can I give specific uses to see all forms?
- I don't want to use Infopath form or any third party form.

**Update** : 
I have found a better way of doing this.
I will create 2 lists, first list will have read/write access to all users, so they can add items and then I will add a workflow to move that item to another list when it is created, second list is where only specif people have access. workflow will move list item quickly, so user will not be able to see any items in the first list.

Comment: do you have a set of people to whom you want to give access for the list?

Comment: yes, I have list of 5 people, 3 will get read and 2 will get full control.

Comment: first you have to create two groups and then in the list setting change the group settings. do you need screenshots?

Comment: If first group has read access, that means they can read all item even not created by them, how would I handle that?

Comment: you can change the advance content type options my mentioning users can read or edit data created by them

Comment: then how would I allow certain people to see all items? for example how site owner will be able to see all items?

Comment: you just have to run a simple workflow. Let us say whenever a user creates a new item you put the site owners name in a people picker field in the list and thus set that setting in the view

Comment: Siteowner name in created by field? I can't see created by field in SharePoint designer workflow update list item action.

Comment: Not in created by but a new People picker field for example : Site Owner. 
So if a new item  is created in list just use
Set field in list function and set Site Owner column to the users name that you want to put.
Then change in the view settings of the list, change the view all items to 
Site owner to [Me]

Answer (score 0):

Few question so some answers

> How can I show a message when form is successfully submitted?

- try to use SP Designer to modify the form and show pop out on item submitted.

> how can I give specific uses to see all forms

- I think you need to give owner rights to someone in the list.